# LibreOffice SUM time period in format HH:MM:SS

Tags: time, sum, libreoffice, calc

I want to obtain the sum of several cells containing a period of time in the format HH:MM:SS.
In LibreOffice Calc 4.0.3.3, I've copy-pasted the periods of time in the range G14:G21, and formatted the cells as Time HH:MM:SS.
I formatted in the same way the cell G22, and inserted in it the following SUM function:

```
=SUM(G14:G21)
```

Instead of the expected result, the function returns me this solution 00:00:00.
Could you explain me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 18):

You have the wrong format. HH wraps around every 24 hours. Try using [HH] instead of HH,
then you get the total number of hours.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was on the way the data were inserted. Even if cells were formatted as Date, analysing them more in detail I found the values were preceded by an ' (apostrophe). Thus means LibreOffice were seeing them as text string and not a period of time. 
Deleting the apostrophe solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be no answer -  here we go:
Formatting the cell(s) [HH]:MM as user defined will resolve your issue. Just had this problem, creating a time record sheet for my wife....

Comment: There were actually three other answers, and I believe [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701245/libreoffice-sum-time-period-in-format-hhmmss/22875695#22875695) covered your response.

Comment: And the response is "format them yourself manually?" well, not really a a professional sounding solution, I mean from LO, not from you guys. I think I will stick to Excel for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Is a special function required to sum a range of hours and minutes? I'm using 6.2.0.3 on macOS and SUM doesn't calculate the value correctly. Oddly, however, if I select all of the cells in the range then the correct value is displayed in the footer bar does. But, for example, `SUM(G1:G15)` doesn't show the correct value.